# Magento 2.0 Rest APi orders - multiple ID filters

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm having a really hard time to retrieve orders by entity_id. I'm calling '/rest/V1/orders' and passing this parameters:

```
{
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]': 'entity_id',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]': '1',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]': 'eq',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]': 'entity_id',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]': '2',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]': 'eq',
  'searchCriteria[current_page]': 1,
  'searchCriteria[page_size]': 100
}
```

When trying to do that it results with an empty array. Using only one filters returns a proper order. I also tried using "in" filter

```
{
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]': 'entity_id',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]': '1,2',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]': 'in'
  'searchCriteria[current_page]': 1,
  'searchCriteria[page_size]': 100
}
```

Passing params like this result in returning order with ID 1, but no order with ID 2. If I change the order of filter value to '2,1' it returns only order with ID 2.

What am I doing wrong here ? What is the proper way of getting orders from REST API by their IDs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be like that:

```
{
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]': 'entity_id',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]': '1, 2',
  'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]': 'in'
}
```

but seems, there are bugs.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2892

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3411

and

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3018

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bugfix while the next release is not out:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/65819d2f61a63e4fa9fc978220f8662ee5472791